# Check if JSON object exist (Postman)

Tags: javascript, json, rest, postman

I am trying to write a test in Postman to check if JSON keys are present in the response I received from the server.

The response:

```
{
  "Result": 0,
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": null,
    "Message": null,
    "StackTrace": null,
    "Errors": null
  },
  "ResponseHeader": {
    "Succeeded": true,
    "Errors": null
  },
  "SessionId": "XXX-XXX-XXX"
}
```

I want to check "Results, Errorcode, Message,Succeeded" etc..

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: share your backend-api

Comment: @ZahidRahman — Why do you need to know details of the backend API in order to answer a question about writing a test against JSON that has already been successfully retrieved?

Comment: @Quentin - the "JSON value check" is checking for json values. e.x :  '"Succeeded": true' - it will check if true is presented. i want to check if Succeeded is presented. i want to achieve a backend api test (so i will know when the schema has changed)

Answer (score 4):

You could check the response scheme using:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests['response json contain Results'] = _.has(jsonData, 'Results');
```

Comment: Is this Underscore.js? How can you use this library in Postman?

Comment: underscore is a builtin and sort of just works no need to declare or require it

Answer (score 2):

According to your response body that you get, You can write simple test script for request under test section.
You need to parse your json response first. The script will look like:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Succeeded with value true"] = jsonData.ResponseHeader.Succeeded === true;
```

similarly you can write tests for other checks.For sessionId I would suggest you to check it with sessionId where it gets generated(store it in environment and check with it in this request)